# Intuitive pop-up keyboard

Tags: keyboard, software-recommendation, onscreen-keyboard

Is there a keyboard threat I can activate with multiple rabbits clicks of the mouse or when I click in a typing field but goes away when a button  is pressed on an actual keyboard.

I guess it's similar to android disappearing after typing on a physical keyboard

Comment: To be clear you are looking for a touch screen keyboard with no touch screen and uses the mouse? Similar to the way the calculator works?

Comment: WinEunuuchs2Unix that's correct I'm not using a touch screen I just want a simple way to use the mouse to complete minor tasks.